# How do I define a function def which accepts arguments and returns a value?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, arguments, function

I would like to be able to define a function which accepts an argument (e.g. a File object), and returns something (e.g. a Boolean), and then pass that function (not the boolean!) to another function and have the accepting function call the sent function.

My background is in Java, and, although I know how to send a function which accepts no arguments and returns nothing in Scala, I can't seem to find a good explanation on the internet for how to do this.

I could implement the program in Java, but I would really like to know how to do it in Scala.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First an example function (actually a method):

```
import java.io.File

def fileExists(file: File) = file.exists
```

and a way to pass that function (actually a method) as an argument to another function (actually... you know...):

```
def findFiles(files: Seq[File], predicate: (File) => Boolean) =
  files filter predicate
```

This method accepts a sequence of files and filters that sequence, picking only files passing a given predicate. In this case we return only existing files:

```
findFiles(Seq(new File("a.txt"), new File("b.txt")), fileExists)
```

See how elegantly we pass `exists` method as an argument? Or if you want to call the predicate manually:

```
def fileMatches(file: File, predicate: (File) => Boolean) =
  predicate(file)
```

#### Side note: "*...actually a method*"

The `findFiles()` *method* takes `predicate` *function* as an argument. However `fileExists()` is a *method* - this works due to a mechanism called *eta-expansion* - transparently wrapping methods into functions.

Comment: Thanks! And I know they're called methods in Java, but I also know that treating... methods... as objects is fundamentally a functional programming construct. I also know that in JavaScript and C++ they're called functions, but they're used for the same things as methods in Java. So, since you have made a point of it, what exactly is the difference between a function, method, and procedure? Or is it purely a language-specific standard sort of thing?

Comment: Also I apologize for answering a question with another question, but if I'm wrong I like knowing exactly why. And if I'm right, I like being equally sure of that.

Comment: @user1470868: actually methods and functions coexist in Scala. Methods are exactly the same thing as methods in Java while functions are objects you can pass around. eta-expansion translates methods to functions transparently. See: [Turning Methods into Functions (or WTF is eta expansion?)](https://gleichmann.wordpress.com/2011/01/09/functional-scala-turning-methods-into-functions/). *Procedures* existed in Pascal and by convention those were functions without return value (`void`).